# Capitalize random rows in Panda Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm making a reverse denoisng autoencoder and I have a dataset but it's all lowercased, but I want 80% of the rows the source entry to be capitalized and only 60% of the target entries to be capitalized. I wrote this

```
import pandas as pd
import torch

df = pd.read_csv('Data/fb_moe.csv')

for i in range(len(df)):
    sample = int(torch.distributions.Bernoulli(torch.FloatTensor([.8])).sample())

    if sample == 1:
        df.iloc[i].y = str(df.iloc[i].y).capitalize()

        sample_1 = int(torch.distributions.Bernoulli(torch.FloatTensor([.6])).sample())

        if sample_1 == 1:
            df.iloc[i].x = str(df.iloc[i].x).capitalize()

df.to_csv('Data/fb_moe2.csv')
```

But this is pretty slow cause my csv is like 8 million rows is there a faster way to do this?

Part of the Dataframe

```
x,y
jon,jun
an,jun
ju,jun
jin,jun
nun,jun
un,jun
jon,jun
jin,jun
nen,jun
ju,jun
jn,jun
jul,jun
jen,jun
hun,jun
ju,jun
hun,jun
hun,jun
jon,jun
jin,jun
un,jun
eun,jun
jhn,jun
```

Comment: Can you show a sample of the dataframe?

Comment: I added it to the qustion

Answer (score 0):

Try adding some boolean mask and some apply functions, pandas does not behave quickly in for loops

```
n = len(df)
source = np.random.binomial(1, p=.8, size=n) ==  1
target = source.copy()

total_source_true = np.sum(source)
target[source] = np.random.binomial(1, p=.6, size=total_source_true) == 1

df.loc[source, 'x'] = df.loc[source, 'x'].str.capitalize()
df.loc[target, 'y'] = df.loc[source, 'y'].str.capitalize()
```